# R: Moving sum of one column in a data frame based on values in other column

Tags: r, sum

I want to calculate a moving sum of one column (populated with ones and zeroes), but only when the value in a corresponding column (time) is within a (moving) range of values.

My data looks like this:

```
values <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
seconds <- c(0.0, 1.0, 2.5, 3.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 8.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.5, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0)
data <- data.frame(values, seconds)
```

Say I want to sum every 5 seconds worth of data in the 'values' column.
Then my first 5-second sum (seconds >=0 & seconds <= 5) would be:

1 (because it corresponds to a 'seconds', 0.0, within the interval of interest)

+

0 (corresponds to 1.0 in 'seconds')

+

0 (2.5)

+

0 (3.0)

= **1**

**STOP**s here because the next value (1) corresponds to 5.5 seconds, outside of the interval.

The next 5-second interval (seconds >= 1 & seconds <= 6) would equal:

0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 = **2**

3rd interval:

(seconds >= 2.5 & seconds <= 7.5) = 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 1 = **3**

and so on.

I'm an R noob, so this is the method I'm using to calculate it (and it is super slow, so I know there must be a better way):

```
for(i in 1:20){movsum[i] <- sum(subset(data, seconds >= (seconds[i] - 5.0) & seconds <= seconds[i])$values)}
```

Thanks for your help. Let me know if there's anything I should clarify.

Comment: Whoops. Fixed it. And I should mention that the movsum loop at the bottom doesn't match up with what I calculated by hand, it's just what I'm generally aiming for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table::foverlaps` solution. The idea here is to create 5 seconds interval look up table and then lookup within `data` which values fall in each interval.

Choose an interval

```
int <- 5 ## 5 seconds
```

The load the package, add additional (identical) column to `data` in order to set boundaries, create a new data set which will have the desired boundaries per row, run `foverlaps`, key `data` in order to enable the binary join, find the corresponding values in `data$values` and sum them per each interval, something like the following seem to work

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(data)[, seconds2 := seconds], seconds, seconds2)
lookup <- data[, .(seconds, seconds2 = seconds + int)]
res <- foverlaps(lookup, data, which = TRUE)[, values := data$values[yid]]
res[, .(SumValues = sum(values)), by = .(SecInterval = xid)]
#     SecInterval SumValues
#  1:           1         1
#  2:           2         2
#  3:           3         3
#  4:           4         3
#  5:           5         3
#  6:           6         2
#  7:           7         1
#  8:           8         2
#  9:           9         1
# 10:          10         2
# 11:          11         3
# 12:          12         3
# 13:          13         2
# 14:          14         2
# 15:          15         1
# 16:          16         0
# 17:          17         0
# 18:          18         0
# 19:          19         0
# 20:          20         0
```

Comment: Nice (+1), much less hardcoding than my attempt.

Comment: @Henrik thanks. It seems like we are not getting same results for different intervals or bigger data set, not sure why.

Comment: @Colin As you can see, both my answer and David's answer agree with the first three values you showed in your question. However, there are some differences between our answers at subsequent time steps. Can you please update your question with the entire desired output for the sample data you provided. Cheers.

Comment: Hi Henrik and David, thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately, the (actual) data I am working with has non-unique time steps -- there are often two events occurring concurrently. So @Henrik as I understand it, it won't really work as a time series. But David's method works for my data (yay!), and both of your answers taught me a lot about R. I really appreciate it, and wish I could give both of you a green check.

Comment: @Colin Regarding "the (actual) data I am working with has non-unique time steps": you should always provide toy data which captures the essence of your real data, and make your example as small as possible. If e.g. time = 1, 2, 2, 2.5, 4 is enough to capture all 'special cases' (irregular time steps, non-unique time steps) well then it's...eeeh...enough. Much easier for potential helpers to see the correspondence between input and desired output, easier to check that their code is working.

Answer (score 3):

You may try some functions from the `zoo` package:

```
library(zoo)

# convert your data to a zoo time series
z <- read.zoo(data, index = "seconds")

# create an empty, regular time series,
# which contains the full time range, in steps of 0.5 sec
z0 <-  zoo(, seq(from = start(z), to = end(z), by = 0.5))

# 'expand' the irregular, original data to a regular series, by merging it with z0 
z2 <- merge(z, z0)

# apply the desired function (sum) to a rolling window of width 11
# (number of observations in each window)
# move the time frame in steps of 2 (by = 2) which correspond to 1 sec 
# use partial = TRUE, to allow the window to pass outside the time range
rollapply(z2, width = 11, by = 2, FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE,
          align = "left", partial = TRUE)

# 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
# 1  2  3  3  3  3  2  2  1  2  2  3  3  2  2  1  0  0  0  0  0
```